# Push notifications don't have corresponding item in inbox

Tags: bug, ios-app

Recently whenever I get a push notification from the Stack Exchange iOS app (likely for someone answering a question of mine or commenting on my posts) if I tap it, it doesn't take me to the corresponding question. So then I open the inbox but I don't see anything new there so I have no idea how to get to the corresponding post.

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone X (iPhone10,3)
- OS Version: Version 11.2.6 (Build 15D100)

Comment: The comment or the post it belongs to is probably already deleted. The app shows those notifications while the site had already deleted them from the notification bar.

Comment: You mean always? Did it happen for the previous comment on this question and this comment?

Comment: For these comments it worked correctly, so I guess it could just be deleted comments. I'm surprised that I get so many comments on my posts that are then deleted.